# adding button to gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I want to add an Update button to my database table in my gridview. I have added a template field but i don't know how to add a button on it.

I'm using asp.net 4.0. In Update method it will change only 1 column called as `kitap_yeri` when button is clicked. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aspx file add the following:

```
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                      AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"/>                        
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

In your .cs file add the following:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...Code...
}
```